# Read Modified By column with pnpjs

Tags: pnp, pnpjs

I want to select the fields I call and get the **Modified By** field - what's the correct way to do this?

```
sp.web.lists
   .getByTitle(myList)
   .items.select(['myId', 'Modified', 'Modified By'])
   .getAll()
   .then(items=> {
      .....
    }) .catch(e=> console.log(e) )
```

It works fine if I take out the Modified By - I also tried **Editor** and had the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editor (Modified by) and Author are people fields. People fields is just a type of a lookup field.

When using REST (or PnPjs), you will notice that all lookup fields should be referenced by their internal name, plus `Id` at the end.

**For example**

- `Author` field should be referenced as `AuthorId`
- MyCustomLookupField should be referenced as `MyCustomLookupFieldId`
- etc.

**Example of a list item. Notice `Id` at the end of the lookup fields**

```
Attachments: false
AuthorId: 10
ComplianceAssetId: null
ContentTypeId: "0x004E9DF1CD4F6A40448A5354540B3D2852"
Created: "2020-10-07T23:14:39Z"
EditorId: 10
FileSystemObjectType: 0
GUID: "19689c78-d238-4d02-ac5a-161cf8e7e0e0"
ID: 1
Id: 1
Modified: "2020-10-07T23:14:39Z"
OData__UIVersionString: "1.0"
ServerRedirectedEmbedUri: null
ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl: ""
Title: "Test List"
```

Example of getting Modified by with

```
const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TestList").items.select("ID, Modified, EditorId").getAll();
console.log(items);
```

[image]

If you want to get User name instead if just an id, you will need to expand the lookup field like so:

```
const items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TestList").items.select("ID, Modified, Editor/Title").expand("Editor").getAll();
console.log(items);
```

[image]